# table data keeps refreshing even if I apply a filter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket

I'm using websocket to get data and to bind it to the html. Here is my code:

```js
 var sock = io('http://myip:8080',{transports: ['websocket']});
  
        sock.on('fetchdata', function(data) {
         var html = '';
         var i;
        

         for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
             html +='<tr class="usrRow usrRow0 ex'+data[i].name+' usrRow'+(i+1)+'" extn="'+data[i].name+data[i].username+'">'+
                                 '<td>'+data[i].name+'</td>'+
                                 '<td>'+data[i].username+'</td>';
                                 
                                               
       html+=   '</tr>';
         }


         $('#showdata').html(html);


         });
```

```html
<table>
<tbody id="showdata">
                           
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the javascript code of my search filter :

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {

                var lastValue = $(this).val();
                console.log(lastValue)
                showHide(lastValue, $('#Activity').val());
            });


function showHide(lastValue, activity) {
                    $(".usrRow").show();

                    var v;
                    if (lastValue.length > 0) {
                        $(".usrRow").each(function() {
                            if ($(this).attr("extn").toLowerCase().indexOf(lastValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                                $(this).show();
                            } else {
                                $(this).hide();
                            }

                            if (activity != "All") {
                                if ($(this).find(".callstatus").html().toLowerCase().replace("&amp;", "&") != activity.toLowerCase()) {
                                    $(this).hide();
                                }
                            }


                        });
                    }
}
```

My problem is that I have a filter in the html to filter the data by typing the name or username etc. The filter works perfectly.

But the search result shows for a second and the table gets refreshed so my search result is gone and the entire table gets displayed.

When I stop the socket service then the data stays there as the table doesn't get refreshed as no data is coming from the socket.

I want the search result to stay as long as there is some text in the search input.
What is wrong with the kind of approach I'm using? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition to check if the search input has some value before you changing the html

```
var sock = io('http://myip:8080',{transports: ['websocket']});

sock.on('fetchdata', function(data) {
    var html = '';
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        html +='<tr class="usrRow usrRow0 ex'+data[i].name+' usrRow'+(i+1)+'" extn="'+data[i].name+data[i].username+'">'+
                                 '<td>'+data[i].name+'</td>'+
                                 '<td>'+data[i].username+'</td>';


        html+=   '</tr>';
    }
    var searchText = $('#Activity').val();
    if(!searchText.length){
        $('#showdata').html(html);
    }


});
```

Comment: this is working for me. But when I have a timer in my code the time get's paused as well

Comment: Where you are printing the timer?

Comment: it's being displayed in the table only. actually time is coming from the socket. so according to your code the time is also paused

Comment: If that is the case, then you can remove the if condition and  call the `showHide(lastValue, $('#Activity').val());` function just after `$('#showdata').html(html);`